# Division sieve operations in Mathematica

Tags: code-request, code-generation

I am just wondering how to easily compute this problem using *Mathematica*.

[What Percent of Even Integers are Divisible by either 6, 20, 28 or 70?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2254278/207778)

My purpose is to extend this to a finite number of factors greater than 4.

Thanks in advance for your help. I know a few *Mathematica* functions but I don't know what to use in this type of problem.

Comment: This seems to be more a question of the underlying math than Mathematica. Could try a search for "inclusion-exclusion methods" to get a start.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Daniel. Indeed to solve the problem, we need to use Exclusion Inclusion Principle. However, computation is tedious for a finitely many facrors. That is why I am asking if there is a  mathematica code available in order to get rid of such tedious computations. About your suggestion, I will try to search for that. Thanks again for the comment. I highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some Mathematica code to add up the appropriate LCMs:

```
list = {6, 20, 28, 70};
Total[Flatten[Table[(-1)^(i - 1)/LCM @@@ Subsets[list, {i}], {i, Length[list]}]]]
47/210
```

If you believe the comments at the linked Mathematics site, this will need to be multiplied by 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer bill. I just have a folow up question before trying the code and accept the answer as correct. I for instance I add another factor say 110.  What I will do then is to  add 110 on the list and change 4 with 5? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, just add the new term to the list (I changed the index on the interator).

Comment: Got it bill. Thanks a lot for your answer and help. Till next time.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {6, 20, 28, 70};
S = Drop[Subsets[list], 1];
R = -2*Sum[(-1)^Length[S[[k]]]/LCM @@ S[[k]], {k, 1, Length@S}];
Print[R*100 // N, "%"]
```

Comment: Thanks Jenny for your answer. I will try your implement your code. Thanks again.